# Pi 4: Keep USB powered when rebooting

Tags: pi-4, usb-power, hat, cluster

I'm using a [ClusterHat v2.3](https://clusterhat.com/) on a Raspberry Pi 4.

On rebooting, the USB Ports losing power, so the cluster nodes as well.

Is there a way to configure the Pi 4 to keep the USB power on when rebooting / be in halt state?

Bootloader config:

```
[all]
BOOT_UART=0
WAKE_ON_GPIO=0
POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=0
DHCP_TIMEOUT=45000
DHCP_REQ_TIMEOUT=4000
TFTP_FILE_TIMEOUT=30000
TFTP_IP=
TFTP_PREFIX=0
BOOT_ORDER=0x1
SD_BOOT_MAX_RETRIES=3
NET_BOOT_MAX_RETRIES=5
[none]
FREEZE_VERSION=0
```

Comment: On their website, it says: Controller Pi can be rebooted without interrupting power to Pi Zeros, network recovers on boot (not available when using a Pi4 controller).

Comment: So the only option is to power both with a USB Hub or similar? (Thought about wiring the Pi 4 power supply with two usb plugs)

Comment: Yeah, you would need a USB hub and ply it in to the raspberry pi, but it should be powered so when the Pi drops power on the USB, it should keep the power going

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found a workaround solution for this issue.

On the ClusterHAT 2.3 the I2C Expander is powered by 3.3V GPIO pin. This is powered off on reboot and resets the power states of the Pi Zeros.

There is no real fix, but a workaround:

#### Set the following properties in firmware

```
WAKE_ON_GPIO=1
POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=0
```

Sources: [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711_bootloader_config.md) and
[that](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/booteeprom.md)

#### Enable sdhci quirks mode

Put `sdhci.debug_quirks2=4` at the end of the line in `/boot/cmdline.txt`

Sources: [this](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/3065) and [that](https://community.blokas.io/t/pisound-with-raspberry-pi-4/1238/12)

#### Power the ClusterHAT with a dedicated power source

Per default the ClusterHAT is powered by 5V GPIO. This can be changed via the 3-part Pad Jumper. Cut connection to GPIO, solder a connection to USB.

[image: change power supply to USB]

Afterwards the ClusterHAT can be powered by USB.

The final step is a hand crafted cable to power the ClusterHAT directly from the USB power supply and also connect the data lines to the Raspberry Pi USB port.

[image: power supply cable]

Now it should be possible to reboot every component without affecting another one.

(Pictures are self-made and copied from [my Blog post](https://serverless.industries/2020/09/18/custerhat-power-issues-solved.html) about this.)